# NFS between ubuntu on different network with vpn?

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, nfs

I am trying to put up a backup server on a ubuntu, with an NFS openend to another network. Here's my setup, roughly visualized.

[image]

Now, the thing is, My machine can ping the backup with the normal network address and due to the VPN, it works backwards as well, though with a different address.

```
(10.0.0.6 --> 10.102.22.61) Works (Pinging eth0 on my backup)
(10.11.22.229 --> 10.0.0.6) Works (Pinging from tun0 on my backup)
```

When I try to mount the share, it comes up with access denied (the adress is allowed in exports)

Any ideas? Can this even work?

Answer (score 0):

Ah. Nevermind.
My problem was a missing route to the VPN network on my VMs. Works now.

```
(route add -net 10.11.22.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gateway 10.0.0.1)
```